# C# XmlDocument.Item property doesn't actually exist?

Tags: c#, xml

According to MSDN there's an "Item" property associated with the XmlDocument class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx

I can't seem to get it to work though.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<item><name>wrench</name></item>");

string myItem = doc.Item["item/name"].InnerText;
```

...fails to compile for example. What's the correct way to use this property if it does exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx) in C# is exposed as a parametrized property called `Item` to other languages.

In C#, just use indexer syntax:

```
var result = someObject["something"];
```

Comment: Thank you, I had tried that but it wasn't working. It appears to work with doc["item"] but doc["item/name"] throws a null object exception. So I'm guessing you can't traverse more than the top level using this notation.

Comment: For processing XML, I'd recommend [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299195.aspx) over XmlDocument. XmlDocument is quite annoying to work with.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach, using **LINQtoXML**

Assuming your XML is going to be always in that structure.

```
string thatXml="<item><name>wrench</name></item>";
XElement elm =XElement.Parse(thatXml); 
string thatValue = elm.Element("name").Value;
```